# jQuery If statement check for active classes of multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a form where if certain buttons have an active state (i.e have been checked) then my final continue button goes green. It's a check to make sure things have been filled in. Here is the jQuery code that I have come up with, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if ($(".button").hasClass("active") && ($(".amd").hasClass("amdactive") || $(".intel").hasClass("intelactive"))) {
    $(".build").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".build").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

The problem I have is that the .build class doesn't have the active class added to it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Will this function constantly check whether these classes are applied? Or does it only do it once on the page load? How can I make it keep checking?

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` How exactly it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @u_mulder The problem I have is that the .build class doesn't have the active class added to it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Will this function constantly check whether these classes are applied? Or does it only do it once on the page load? How can I make it keep checking?

Comment: Currently it just checks once when page loads.

Comment: The check in domready event is raised once, you have to fire your check when you need it

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but how would I do that? I need it so that once those buttons have their respective classes apply, the final button becomes active.

Comment: @Beau you may include your html here and create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @caramba http://jsfiddle.net/hp7yztzc/

Comment: You need to run that code within change handlers of your form

Comment: I'm sorry but how would I go about that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: All that is a little bit lost on me. Any help there?

Comment: if you don't follow what a change handler is you should study some form processing tutorials. This is fairly `form 101` stuff